# how to run .exe file of a java file in other computers

Tags: java, eclipse, exe, executable-jar

I have developed a java code in eclipse.My code reads data from a .txt file by using server_ip. I have created an executable jar file of the code and then created an .exe file using launch4j. The .exe file shows data if I run it in my laptop,but it does not show any data if I run it in other pc. then it shows null point exception. my operating system is windows 7-32 bit. I am giving my code here. please give me solutions.

package remotedata;

```
import java.awt.*;
```

import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*;

```
public class remotedataread extends Frame
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException{

        BufferedReader br = null;
        TextArea FileText = 
        new TextArea(" Content of the File \'temp1.txt\' :"); 

        try
        {   
            URL url = 
                new URL("file://server_ip/path_file.txt");

                        InputStream is = url.openStream(); 
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                     /*   String line = null;
                        while (true) {
                            line = br.readLine();
                            if (line == null) {
                                //wait until there is more of the file for us to read
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }
                        }*/
        }


        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Bad URL");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }   

        FileText.setBackground(Color.white);
        FileText.append(String.valueOf('\n'));

        Frame f = new Frame("server data");
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.add(FileText); 
        f.setVisible(true);

        try
        {
            String s;
            s=null;
            boolean eof = false;
            //while (true) {
            s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Time    Temperature");
            while( !eof )
            {
                FileText.append(s + String.valueOf('\n'));
                try
                {
                    s = br.readLine();
                    if ( s == null )
                    {
                                //  eof = true;
                    //  br.close();
                         Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }
                    else{
                        //System.out.println("Time  Temperature");
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                }
                catch (EOFException eo)
                        {
                                eof = true;
                        }
                catch (IOException e)
                        {
                                System.out.println("IO Error : "+e.getMessage());
                        }
            }
            //}

        }
        catch (IOException e)
                {
                        System.out.println("IO Error : "+e.getMessage());
                }

    } 

}
```

Comment: which line does the null pointer exception happen? Also does the jar file otherwise work?

Comment: no, none of the jar file and exe works in other pc. this is the error :I0 Error: Connection refused:connect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullpointerExcwption at remotedata.remotedataread.main<remotedataread.java:60>

Comment: i see line 60 in this code is a { can you copy the line where the exception occurs and add to your question

Comment: i have found this line as line 60:  while( !eof )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe , you're application is not able to connect to the other node ..hence its throwing a NullPointer exception .Make sure that computers are in the Network

Answer (score 0):

your prolem seems to be here:

```
 URL url = 
            new URL("file://server_ip/path_file.txt");

                    InputStream is = url.openStream(); 
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

the url "file://server_ip/path_file.txt" is valid on your laptop, but not on other pc's

Comment: what should be the solution? can you help me plz?

Comment: You have to use correct url to file, currently you gives the path to a file on your executing machine. If this is a file on a remote server, you need to give remote ip or url.

Comment: but when the .exe file is running it is showing the error:I0 Error: Connection refused:connect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullpointerExcwption at remotedata.remotedataread.main<remotedataread.java:60>

Comment: try to put your url file://server_ip/path_file.txt in webbrowser on your laptop and other pc and you will see the difference. The exception is like FileNotFound exception for URL's. I think if you replaces 'server_ip' with correct ip, it should work on every  pc in the same network